# How to run a crontab job only if a file exists?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

Is it possible to check for a file existence in a crontab oneliner, and only execute a script if that file existed?

Pseudocode:

```
* * * * * <if /tmp/signal.txt exists> run /opt/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Is adding the test to the start of the script an option? `[ -f /tmp/signal.txt ] || exit`.

Comment: Note that the cron job will still _run_ (complete with log messages and possibly emails) - the test is _part of_ the job.  So the title disagrees with the content of the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use an ordinary test for existence, then run the script if the test succeeds.

```
* * * * *       if [ -e /tmp/signal.txt ]; then /opt/myscript.sh; fi
```

or

```
* * * * *       if test -e /tmp/signal.txt; then /opt/myscript.sh; fi
```

Or, using the short-circuit syntax. Doing it this way would cause the job to *fail* if the file does not exist (which may trigger an email from the cron daemon):

```
* * * * *       [ -e /tmp/signal.txt ] && /opt/myscript.sh
```

or

```
* * * * *       test -e /tmp/signal.txt && /opt/myscript.sh
```

You could use the `-f` test instead of the `-e` test if you want to additionally ensure that `/tmp/signal.txt` is a regular file and not a directory, named pipe, or some other type of file.

Comment: Note that the typical isc cron will _not_ send an email if the return code is just non-zero, only if it produces any _output_. Other variants might, though. Check the documentation of your cron daemon for its actual behavior.

Comment: Also note-worthy here is `test -x /opt/myscript.x` to test if it's executable before trying to run it.

Comment: @kusalananda My cronjob not kicked of when there are multiple files with same extenstion present:

`test -e /home/prodop/agupta/*.ksh`

If only one .ksh is present then its working fine but when i kept multiple ksh it's not working.. Thanks!!!

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Yes, this is why none of my examples use filename globbing patterns in the test.  If you want to test for the existence of any file with a `.ksh` filename suffix, you need to do that in two steps:  `set -- ~prodop/agupta/*.ksh; [ -e "$1" ] && some-command`.  This expands the globbing pattern and then tests whether the first thing that the pattern expanded to exists.

Comment: @Kusalananda 43 16 * * * set -- ~home/prodop/agupta/*.xml; [ -e "$1" ] && /home/prodop/agupta/sendmail.ksh > /home/prodop/agupta/log.log, I tried this way not worked

Comment: What significance of `~` to keep before prodop i tried kept just before home dint worked and when i kept it befor prodop its worked. I am wondering. Actually i have to check somewhere in other directory. Above was my test directory

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I shortened the path from `/home/prodop/agupta` to `~prodop/agupta` since I assumed `prodop` was a username and `/home/prodop` was its home directory. Using `~home` makes no sense unless you have a user called `home`.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to adapt full `systemd` over `cron`, one could use `ConditionPathExists=/path/to/file` in the `[Unit]` section of the service.

---

Checking if the path is a file can be a bit more complicated, as the direct test like `ConditionIsFile` does not exist.

**Option 1** One knows that the file will never be empty allows for using `ConditionFileNotEmpty=/path/to/file`

**Option 2** If the file may also be of zero size and one needs to check for mere existence and it being a file, one could test for the existence of the path and it *not* being a directory:

```
ConditionPathExists=/path/to/file
ConditionPathIsDirectory=!/path/top/file
```

Where `=!` is a logical **NOT** operator.

Comment: Could that test be made to take file type into account (i.e. regular file and not directory)?

Comment: @Kusalananda not as quickly as with `[ -f /path/to/file ]` but possible. See updates.

Comment: Typically unprivileged users have access to cron but not systemd.

Comment: @Joshua Users may define and run their user-specific services. see [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User)

Comment: Which doesn't magically allow them to run code while not logged in. It has to be turned on for every user by root according to your own link.